# Magento 2 Adding Wysiwyg to Custom Tab in Catalog_Product_New

Tags: wysiwyg, magento2

I have successfully added a custom tab in the product admin page, and can save it in the database and display it on the frontend, however I am wanting to add a Wysiwyg editor for the body content and I can't seem to get it to display properly

Here are code examples so you can better understand my problem:

Inside my di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">JP\AskedFreq\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomFieldset</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Inside DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomFieldset.php

```
<?php
namespace JP\AskedFreq\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg;
```

use     Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
    use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
    use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Textarea;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;

```
class CustomFieldset extends AbstractModifier
{


/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface
 */
protected $locator;

/**
 * @var ArrayManager
 */
protected $arrayManager;

/**
 * @var UrlInterface
 */
protected $urlBuilder;

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $meta = [];

protected $editor;


/**
 * @param LocatorInterface $locator
 * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
 * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
 */
public function __construct(
    LocatorInterface $locator,
    ArrayManager $arrayManager,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder


)
{
    $this->locator = $locator;
    $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;

}

/**
 * Data modifier, does nothing in our example.
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 */
public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    return $data;
}

/**
 * Meta-data modifier: adds ours fieldset
 *
 * @param array $meta
 * @return array
 */
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    $this->meta = $meta;
    $this->addCustomFieldset();

    return $this->meta;
}

/**
 * Merge existing meta-data with our meta-data (do not overwrite it!)
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function addCustomFieldset()
{
    $this->meta = array_merge_recursive(
        $this->meta,
        [
            static::CUSTOM_FIELDSET_INDEX => $this->getFieldsetConfig(),
        ]
    );
}

/**
 * Declare ours fieldset config
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getFieldsetConfig()
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Frequently Asked Questions'),
                    'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => static::DATA_SCOPE_PRODUCT, // save data in the product data
                    'provider' => static::DATA_SCOPE_PRODUCT . '_data_source',
                    'ns' => static::FORM_NAME,
                    'collapsible' => true,
                    'sortOrder' => 10,
                    'opened' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'children' => [
            static::CONTAINER_HEADER_NAME => $this->getHeaderContainerConfig(10),
            static::FIELD_NAME_BODY => $this->getTextAreaFieldConfig(40),
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Get config for header container
 *
 * @param int $sortOrder
 * @return array
 */
protected function getHeaderContainerConfig($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => null,
                    'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                    'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                    'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'content' => __('Frequently Asked Questions'),
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'children' => [],
    ];
}


protected function getTextAreaFieldConfig($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Body'),
                    'componentType' => Wysiwyg::NAME,
                    'formElement' => Wysiwyg::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => static::FIELD_NAME_BODY,
                    'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'options' => $this->_getOptions(),
                    'visible' => true,
                    'disabled' => false,
                    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

}

Inside the getTextAreaFieldConfig function I am trying to call the Wyiwyg form element but it does not appear.

Any advice on how I can do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm trying to figure out the same thing in category attributes.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not, instead I created a Wysiwyg Widget, this was actually what we wanted as it allowed us to create specific blocks that could be placed where we specified it. If this is something you are interested in doing I can help lead you in the right direction.